# Elemente will make it invisible when clicked script in php

Tags: javascript, php, css, hide, visibility

German will not appear when clicked and will show english. If English is clicked, German will appear. I've investigated hide, show, visibile parts. I even wrote a JavaScript script, but it did not work. At the moment, German and English appear to be on the side of the site, but I want only German and German will be clicked and the German page will be English.

```
<?php
 session_start();
 if($_GET['lang']) {
  $_SESSION['lang'] = $_GET['lang'];
header("Location:index.php"); 
   }
  if ($_SESSION['lang'] == "en") {
$lang= "en";
 }
  elseif ($_SESSION['lang'] == "gr") {
  $lang= "gr";
 }
else {
  $lang= substr($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'],0,2);
 }
include 'languages/'.$lang.'.php';
  ?>

<a href="?lang=gr" style="text-decoration:none;" title="German">
<strong>German</strong> </a>
<a href="?lang=en" style="text-decoration:none;" title="English"><strong>English</strong></a>
```

Comment: `gr` for German?

Comment: @kerbholz yes right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP only (index.php)

```
<html>
    <body>
        <h1>My page</h1>
        <?php
            if(isset($_GET["lang"])){
                if($_GET["lang"] == "gr"){
                    echo '<a href="index.php?lang=en" style="text-decoration:none;" title="English"><strong>English</strong></a>';
                    /* include('gr_content.php'); */
                } else if($_GET["lang"] == "en"){
                    echo '<a href="index.php?lang=gr" style="text-decoration:none;" title="German"><strong>German</strong></a>';
                    /* include('en_content.php'); */
                } else {
                    echo 'no lang';
                }
            } else {
                echo '<a href="index.php?lang=en" style="text-decoration:none;" title="English"><strong>English</strong></a>';/* include("gr_content.php);*/

            }
        ?>
    </body></html>
```

JS only

```js
var dict = {
                "gr" : {"div1" : "german content 1", "div2" : "german content 2"},
                "eng" : {"div1" : "eng content 1", "div2" : "eng content 2"}
            };
            
            function displayer(lang){
                Object.keys(dict[lang]).forEach(function(k) {
                    document.getElementById(k).innerHTML = dict[lang][k];
                });
            }
            
            function grClick(){
                document.getElementById("gr").style.display = 'none';
                document.getElementById("eng").style.display = 'block';
                displayer("gr");
            }
            
            function engClick(){
                document.getElementById("gr").style.display = 'block';
                document.getElementById("eng").style.display = 'none';
                displayer("eng");
            }
            
            displayer("gr");
```

```html
<html>
 <body>
     <h1>My page</h1>
     <a id="gr" href="#" style="text-decoration:none;display:none;" title="German" onclick="grClick()"><strong>German</strong></a>
        <a id="eng" href="#" style="text-decoration:none;" title="English" onclick="engClick()"><strong>English</strong></a>
        <div id="div1"></div><br>
        <div id="div2"></div>    
        </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much but i dont want Select your language on the page will be only German and click English will come.

Comment: smth like that ?

Comment: Yes right:) finally I can do english as default by default without opening index.php. for example www.food.com/soup  site default english

Comment: you have full php or full javascript, try it with the snippet to see if it's what you wanted